# Time of Nasdaq daily close price

Tags: pricing, asset-pricing, intraday, nasdaq

On the Nasdaq [website](https://www.nasdaq.com/articles/what-time-does-the-stock-market-open-and-close-2016-05-11) It Is stated that the market closes at 4:00pm.

However I have historic intraday minute prices and I can see that that are minutes with prices after 4:00 PM (I am assuming its [After-Hours Trading](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/after-hours-trading-am-i-able-to-trade-at-this-time/)).
I also have historic daily prices.

My question is about the close price (not adjusted close) of the daily data. Is it simply the close price of the minute at 4:00 PM? or Is it the price at 8:00 PM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither.  Nasdaq publishes a close price at 4:01:30 p.m. ET known as the Nasdaq Official Close Price ("NOCP").  Nasdaq also amends this price up to 5:15 p.m. ET if any trades that were used to calculate the NOCP are canceled or corrected.

You can get NOCP prices directly from Nasdaq each day on their website.

Information Links:

[NOCP PDF](https://www.nasdaqtrader.com/Content/NewsAlerts/2003/vendoralerts/nva2003-6c.pdf)

[Nasdaq Press Release](http://ir.nasdaq.com/news-releases/news-release-details/nasdaq-launches-nasdaq-official-closing-price)

Comment: so NOCP doesn't consider after hours trading? or at least the full duration of it

Comment: It does not consider after hours trading.  I have added a link to the answer that has some explanation and examples